# Systemd $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set

Tags: linux, systemd

When I start systemd as root on my linux mint 18.2 vm it gives me the following error message :

> Trying to run as user instance, but $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is not set.

I checked the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR as user and it gave me /run/user/1000, but i am not able to run systemd as user as it then gives me this error :

> Failed to create
>   /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c2.scope/init.scope control group:
>   Permission denied
>
> Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied

When i am root the command `"echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"` gives me no output.

Any possible solutions?